# How do I save outlook Mailitem as sent mail

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, mailitem

I have created an Outlook mail item and want to save it in a folder as a sent mail. I was able to set sender mail using `mail.SentOnBehalfofName`. How do I add Date field to this. I have some eml emails which I want to add to folder without a paid library. I was able to parse and save it to an outlook folder but the date field is set to None. Can someone help either to set the date field to the outlook `mailitem` object or a way to create mail Items that can be saved in outlook with all the properties?

Comment: You really need to show the code that sets the properties

Comment: `Outlook.MailItem tempMail = application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                
                mail.To = "abc@mno.com";
                mail.Subject = "hello World";
                mail.Body = "bla bla";
                mail.SentOnBehalfOfName "xyz@mno.com";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, item's sent state can only be changed before it is saved for the very first time (MAPI limitation). Secondly, Outlook always creates `olMailItem` objects in the unsent state. The only item created in the sent state is the `PostItem` (`olPostItem`). You can create a PostItem, change its MessageClass property to "IPM.Note", save it, then release it using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` (to make sure Outlook forgets about it), then reopen it by caling`Namespace.GetItemFromID` - this time Outlook should return back a `MailItem` object (instead of the original `PostItem`).

Keep in mind that the icon will be wrong, hence the post icon needs to be removed - delete the `PR_ICON_INDEX` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003`) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperty`.

Also keep in mind that Outlook will not let you set some properties it considers "important" - such as the message dates, sender entry id, etc. And setting just the `SentOnBehalfOfName` property won't be enough - the sender entry ids must be set, or the user won't be able to correctly reply to that message.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) is an option, creating a message in the sent state is as easy as

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  set Msg = Inbox.Items.Add
  Msg.Sent = true
  set CU = Session.CurrentUser
  set recip = Msg.Recipients.AddEx(CU.Name, CU.SmtpAddress, "SMTP", olTo)
  Msg.Subject = "fake received message"
  Msg.Body = "just a test"
  vSenderEntryId = Session.AddressBook.CreateOneOffEntryID("Joe The Sender", "SMTP", "joe@domain.demo", false, true)
  set vSender = Session.AddressBook.GetAddressEntryFromID(vSenderEntryId)
  Msg.Sender = vSender
  Msg.SentOnBehalfOf = vSender
  Msg.SentOn = Now
  Msg.ReceivedTime = Now
  Msg.Save
```

Comment: Firstly i would like to thank @DmitryStreblechenko, for past couple of months I have been working on an Outlook plugin, and every hurdle I ever faced and searched for hours on stack overflow Dmitry had an answer to almost all, I would love to use Redemption it would solve all my problems in an instance but my org has a tedious process to use a new 3rd party lib... :(
I have given up on try to make it seem like a sent item now, I am trying to write a MSG parser to set these properties while creating the msg from data.